# How to activate or deactivate babel layout locally

Tags: macros, babel, right-to-left

Consider this example, how to deactivate tabular layout in RTL context

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters.lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
right text & left text  
\end{tabular}

% macro to deactivate tabular layout  

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
left text & right text  
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no in-built command, but you can save the original definition before loading babel:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\@oritabular\@tabular
\newcommand\restoretabularlayout{\let\@tabular\@oritabular}
\makeatother

\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters.lists.tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
right text & left text
\end{tabular}

% macro to deactivate tabular layout
{
\restoretabularlayout

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
left text & right text
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
left text & right text
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how about adding layouts mid document,  I think  it is better if there is commands like `\addlayout{...}`  and `\removelayout{...}`

Comment: Make a feature request.